# Where condition on a column datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a table with multiple columns and 3.5 million lines. I am trying to write a select statement where I can select all the lines where data type of column B does not fall under *Date* datatype. Simple example

```
Column A     Column B
abc          10/20/2014
cde          abd 04/10/201 e
```

output will be

```
Column A            Column B
cde                abd 04/10/201 e
```

Note column B is nvarchar(255), null as datatype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[`TRY_CAST()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** or **[`TRY_CONVERT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** and check for `NULL`

```
SELECT <Columns Here>
FROM <Table Name Here>
WHERE TRY_CAST(<Column Name Here> AS DATE) IS NULL;
```

But, I'll suggest to change the datatype of that column to the right datatype, which is `DATE`/`DATETIME`, that ensure that the data is dates only, and you won't fall in this problem. Storing dates as strings is really a bad practices you should avoid, those datatypes are there for reason, so use them wisely. That's the right way.

Answer (score 3):

Look into [`TRY_CONVERT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

```
select ColumnA
    , ColumnB
from YourTable
where TRY_CONVERT(date, ColumnB) IS NULL
```

Comment: Much better than my answer. +1